# To achieve maximum flavour is it better to cut or tear basil leaves?

Tags: basil

When I add basil to a dish should I tear or cut basil leaves?
Does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tearing is for artistic effect

Some people will claim tearing does not damage the cell of the plant as much as cutting, a simple look under a basic microscope will show you otherwise. Not sure how this would affect basil in particular. What dish are you preparing?

If you want more basil flavour and smell, cut it more finely, or bruise it (back of knife or rolling pin) to release more oils just before serving

Comment: If you want a case study of tearing, [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/24227/10565) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to cut basil with a knife, gently rub olive oil all over it before you cut it, this will prevent the leaves from darkening , particularly if you are using it in a salad.

Comment: Great tip, you must really know your basil