# Is there a compressed gas device designed specifically for creating infusions?

Tags: equipment, gas, infusion

[This answer about creating infusions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/24431/14563) suggests using a compressed gas siphon to quickly infuse liquids with flavours from 'fragile' herbs.

[The manufacturer of the popular iSi compressed gas siphons](http://www.isisnorthamerica.com) seems to sell [whipped cream](http://www.isinorthamerica.com/consumer/products/easy-whip/en/) and [soda siphons](http://www.isinorthamerica.com/consumer/products/soda-siphon/en/), but neither is advertised for the aforementioned infusion purpose.  I'm not at all averse to using one of these devices for this different purpose from that which it was designed, but I'd like to find the most usable device for creating infusions using compressed gas.

This leaves me with the following questions:

1. Is there a compressed gas device designed specifically for creating infusions using [this method](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/24431/14563)?
2. In general, would a soda siphon or a whipped cream siphon be more suited to creating infusions?
3. Are there particular attributes to look for in a compressed gas siphon that lend themselves to creating infusions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I do not think so, the technique was described in e.g. modernist cuisine, they suggest using a ISI siphone and if I can remember correctly does not describe any other tool. Any pressure chamber would work, if you have access to one :-)

2) I have something like [this](http://www.isinorthamerica.com/foodservice/products/gourmet-whip-plus/en/) which can be charged with both soda and cream charges, that is what I woudl suggest. (mine is not ISI). Think both you show will work since both charges are the same.  Charge with N2O (cream charge).

3) For the infusion part, you want pressure, look for size of the device that suits your needs. The bigger, the more you can do at the same time, but will require more charges for same pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the product you mention, or at least a very similar product, is advertised for that purpose. They even sell [some extra](https://isi-store.com/collections/accessories/products/rapid-infusion-tool-5-piece-kit-with-recipe-book) parts to make that easier - it's not quite clear to me what the extra parts are supposed to do, it's possible they just allow you to let the gas out at the end without making a mess.

iSi Rapid Infusion set:
[image: iSi Kisag Rapid Infusion]

Comment: It's probably better to link to the company's website, rather than one of the resellers, especially as it's a non-English reseller, and the answers are all in English : https://isi-store.com/products/rapid-infusion-starter-kit  (although buy it from one of the resellers ... $32 vs. $200 MSRP)

Comment: @Joe The company structure is very unclear to me, the company I linked to certainly claims to have invented the device, and the siphon I bought from them has their name and only their name on it. But the accessory kit does say Isi and the point about the language is true. The price difference is because your link includes the siphon and my original link does not.